# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-insert, executemany

I created the following table:

```
sql_command = """CREATE TABLE users (
id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255),
company VARCHAR(255));"""
```

When I run the following:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO users(id, name, company) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""
crsr.execute(sql, ("value", "value", "value"))
```

I get and error message:

```
File "test.py", line 50, in analyzeUsers
    crsr.execute(sql, ("value", "value", "value"))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

Any idea?

Comment: sqlite3 uses qmarks for param placeholders: `?` not `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

As Parfait mentioned, I should have used `?` instead of `%s` when using SQLite.